# How to to fit scrollbar approriately?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I am new to tkinter and python3. I have worked on creating a scrollbar for a frame that is a child of a canvas which is also a child of Toplevel(). The scrollbar buttons function well but the bar/box itself stretches from top to bottom and cannot move. Furthermore, using the scroll buttons, the user can scroll way beyond the content (where there nothing to view).
Here is the code.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from tkinter import *
from filegroups import typeGroups

app = Tk()

types_window = Toplevel(app)
types_window.wm_title('Types')

yscrollbar = Scrollbar(types_window, orient=VERTICAL)
yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)

canvas = Canvas(types_window,
                 width = 300, 
                 height = 500, 
                 yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)

canvas.grid(row=0,column=0)
canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
yscrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

frame = Frame(canvas)

canvas.create_window(0,0,anchor=NW,window=frame)

for key in sorted(typeGroups.keys()):
    options_frame = LabelFrame(frame, text=key)
    options_frame.grid(padx=5, pady=10)
    for item in typeGroups[key]:
        item_button = Checkbutton(options_frame,
                                  text=item)
        item_button.grid()

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the canvas scrollregion after filling the frame with labels by adding these two lines just before `app.mainloop()`:

```
canvas.update_idletasks()
canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
```

The call to `update_idletasks` is needed to ensure that the canvas content is updated before we ask for the bounding box.